# How can I define a LISP function, which takes in an array as an argument?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I want to create an array in a function and pass it as a parameter to another function, which is called from that function. How can I do that? Here's the pseudo code:

```
define FuncA (Array Q){
    <whatever>
}

define FuncB (n){
    make-array myArray = {0,0,....0}; <initialise an array of n elements with zeroes>
    FuncA(myArray); <call FuncA from FuncB with myArray as an argument>
}
```

Comment: Had you tried something that suggested you needed to do something specific to accept an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common Lisp is dynamically typed, so an array parameter is declared in the same way as any other parameter, without its type:

```
(defun funcA (Q)
  Q) ; just return the parameter

(defun funcB (n)
  (let ((arr (make-array n :initial-element 0)))
    (funcA arr)))
```

or, if you don't need create a binding, simply

```
(defun funcB (n)
  (funcA (make-array n :initial-element 0)))
```

Testing

```
? (funcB 10)
#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

If you want to check that the parameter is of the expected type, you can use `typep`, `type-of`, `typecase` or `check-type`, for example:

```
(defun funcA (Q)
  (check-type Q array)
  Q)
```

then

```
? (funcA 10)
> Error: The value 10 is not of the expected type ARRAY.
> While executing: FUNCA, in process Listener(4).
```